# How i able to link following data

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, multimap

i have issues to link 3 element (s start, stop) together in the following code.

```
 map <int, int> (start, stop) startomap;
 map <unsigned, <int, int> > (n1, startomap);
 map <string, unsigned> (s, n1) m3;
```

from m3 i am able to link string and n1,
     how i set-up a map < string,  > (s, startomap) m4;
     and at the same time make sure the 1 to 1 relationship between s -> n-> start->to
     Thanks a lot!

Comment: you would want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606004/c-multi-dimensional-data-handling to approach the above problem in a different manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
map <int, int>  startomap;
map<unsigned, map<int, int> > n1startomap;
map <string, map<unsigned, map<int, int> > > sn1startmap;
```

Comment: thanks! i think it might be better  to just put <n1, start, stop> into a structure/class. then use map <string, class>